# What is the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{x-1}{(x+1)(x^2 + 5x + 5)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Start by finding coefficients $A_0, B_0$ and $B_1$ such that $$\frac{x - 1}{(x+1)(x^2 + ax + 5)} = \frac{A_0}{x+1} + \frac{B_0 + B_1x}{x^2 + ax + 5}.$$

Multiplying out and equating the numerators yields the following system of linear equations:
\begin{align}
A_0 + 0B_0 + B_1 &= 0 \\
aA_0 + B_0 + 0B_1 &= 1 \\
5A_0 + B_0 + 0B_1 &= -1
\end{align}
By row reduction we can see that the solutions are $A_0 = \frac{2}{a-5}, B_0 = 1 - \frac{2a}{a-5}, B_1 = -\frac{2}{a-5}$, provided $a \neq 5$.

I don't understand what goes wrong here if $a = 5$. The polynomial $x^2 + 5x + 5$ has the two real roots $r_0 = \frac{-5 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $r_1 = \frac{-5 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$, and it seems that $$\frac{x - 1}{(x+1)(x-r_0)(x-r_1)}$$
should have a partial fraction decomposition as $$\frac{A_0}{x + 1} + \frac{B_0}{x - r_0} + \frac{C_0}{x - r_1}.$$

So what is going on here?

**EDIT:** The system of linear equations was incorrect. Thanks to the commenter below for pointing that out. The second equation should be $$aA_0 + B_0 + B_1 = 1$$ and the solutions are $A_0 = \frac{2}{a-6}, B_0 = 1 - 2\frac{a-1}{a-6}, B_1 = -\frac{2}{a-6}$, provided $a \neq 6$. Now it's clear why this doesn't work because the polynomial $x^2 + 6x + 5$ has roots $r_0 = -1$ and $r_1 = -5$, so we should write the rational function as $$\frac{x+1}{(x+1)^2(x+5)}$$ which should factor as $$\frac{A_0 + A_1x}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{B_0}{x+5}.$$

Comment: I think the second equation should have $B_1$ rather than $0B_1.$

Comment: @B.Goddard Ah yes you are right, sorry. I will redo this.

Comment: @B.Goddard Updated the question, thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Correction: the correct decomposition is $\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+5}$

Comment: $\frac{A_0}{x+1} + \frac{B_0 + B_1x}{x^2 + 5x + 5}$ is partial fraction expansion over the rationals. And $\frac{A_0}{x + 1} + \frac{B_0}{x - r_0} + \frac{C_0}{x - r_1}$ is over the reals.  They will give you equivalent answers.  If you are doing this in order to integrate, the first one will give you something with an arctanh term, while the second one will give you something strictly with logarithms.